# Kotlin ignore null keys on map

Tags: kotlin

I have a list of objects that looks like that:

```
class Attachment(
        val attachmentId: Int,
        val attachmentName: String?,
        val size: Long
)
```

I wanna have a hash map that uses the `attachmentName` as the key and the whole class as the value.

The issue is that the `attachmentName` can be null, I wanna ignore these items (with null on `attachmentName` so that they wont appear on the hash map)

I wanna know if there's an elegant was to do it in Kotlin
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you don't want to add them to the map in the first place, then just filter them out before adding, e.g.:

```
val map = myAttachments.filter{ it.attachmentName != null }
                       .associateBy{ it.attachmentName!! }
```

This is a bit ugly, as the `associateBy()` doesn't know that the `attachmentName` can't be null, so if you want the map's key type to be non-nullable you have to force it with `!!`.

Another approach would be to do the filtering at the same time as creating the mappings:

```
val map = myAttachments.mapNotNull {
        if (it.attachmentName != null)
            attachmentName to it
        else
            null
    }.toMap()
```

…but that's longer and creates more temporary objects.

Note that some map implementations don't support null keys, so the alternative of creating the map and then removing items with a null key is risky and would depend upon the exact implementation.

Answer (score 1):

use `filterKeys`

```
myHashMap.filterKeys { it != null }
```